# What is this wooden object in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing minecraft and suddenly in a big mob fight, I see this wooden objects left behind. What are they? They are shown in the image

[image: I am looking at this wooden object]

I have never seen anything like it, I have no idea what it is called to google it, so can someone please explain these to me?

I later found out that they are arrows that have been shot by skeletons, but why wooden plank arrows?

Comment: Can you edit your post to add more perspectives? I can't really see anything from this angle

Comment: This is vanilla with no data packs, right? Did you by perchance had an armor stand nearby?

Comment: Can you mine some blocks around it to get a better view? Can't see much and it looks like it's going through the block.

Comment: It almost looks like a big amount of arrows, but they wouldn't align that way, they would have random rotations. So I agree with the others, more angles and mining around it would be helpful. And checking if there are datapacks or resource packs enabled (can happen without you doing anything if you joined a server).